# the related record does not change after update execution with no error using EF

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I use EF and have this code in update action in my Repository

```
        public void Update(ValueField valueField)
        {
        var db = new myEntities();
        var updatingRow = Find(valueField);
        updatingRow.ValueFieldID = valueField.ValueFieldID;
        updatingRow.ProductTypeID = valueField.ProductTypeID;

        db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I have no error and there is not any exceptions , but related record in my table in database does not change.
what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```
var updatingRow = Find(valueField);
```

is not using your current context meaning that `db` doesn't see anything to change. Change it to:

```
var updatingRow = db.Find(valueField);
```

Comment: Find is a function in my repository which does this

Comment: But Find us clearly using it's own instance of `myEntities` so your local version (`db`) doesn't track the changes.